# Spring Security - check if web url is secure / protected

Tags: spring-security

Is there a way to "ask" spring security if the current request is secure? Because even if I am authenticated I want to detect if I am in a secure protected URL or in a anonymous / public page

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean request including intercept-url pattern or it is ssl authenticated?

Comment: i mean intercept-url pattern and secured annotation.

Comment: I want to test that the current request I am in, is either anonymous or it has been marked as secured either using a config or using @Secured annotation

Comment: Where you able to resovle this? I'd like to know too if the request URL shall be protected.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security provides [JSP tag support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#taglibs-authorize) for this. For example:

```
<sec:authorize url="/admin">

This content will only be visible to users who are authorized to access the "/admin" URL.

</sec:authorize>
```

Thymeleaf provides a Spring Security Dialect that has direct support for [checking URL authorization](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity#using-the-attributes) with Spring Security. For example:

```
<div sec:authorize-url="/admin">
    This will only be displayed if authenticated user can call the "/admin" URL.
</div>
```

If your technology does not support performing the check directly, you can easily use the [WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html) (this is the object that the JSP taglib and Thymeleaf use). For example, you can `@Autowire` an instance of `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` and use it directly. Obviously the syntax will vary depending on where you use it (i.e. GSP, Freemarker, etc), but here is an example in straight Java code.

```
@Autowired
WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator webPrivs;

public void useIt() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    boolean hasAdminAccess = webPrivs.isAllowed("/admin", authentication);

    boolean hasAdminPostAccess = webPrivs.isAllowed(null, "/admin", "POST", authentication);
}
```

Comment: This is right but it only works for url patterns defined in spring-security.xml (not for @PreAuthorize annotated controller methods) as i noticed some time ago. You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984557/is-it-possible-to-know-if-a-url-is-accesible-when-using-spring-mvc-and-spring-se

Comment: How can I obtain this WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator when I do not use Spring Context?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your own implementation for `AccessDecisionVoter`  then just simply override [Vote](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html#vote%28org.springframework.security.core.Authentication,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Collection%29) method and compare intercept url using `filterInvocation.getRequestUrl();` method.

```
@Override
public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation filterInvocation,
    Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
  String requestUrl = filterInvocation.getRequestUrl();
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can mark it is as secure channel so converted to https:// url.

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" requires-channel="https" />
```

We can then use request.getScheme() to identify it.
I used org.springframework.security.version 3.1.4.RELEASE