# Spring security check if user has access to mentioned url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have started using spring security, and after a lot of research I am not able to find an answer for:

If I explicitly want to check if user A have access to stuff B. I can check this with JSP tag support [Spring Security - check if web url is secure / protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236448/spring-security-check-if-web-url-is-secure-protected) like

```
<sec:authorize url="stuff/B">
```

But what if I want to check the same thing in the controller(java class). I am not finding any spring function here to check if a login user has access to mentioned url(https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint from the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html):

> to use this tag there must also be an instance of `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` in your application context. If you are using the namespace, one will automatically be registered. This is an instance of `DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`,"

And in the javadoc of [`DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html), we can see a [`isAllowed`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html#isAllowed-java.lang.String-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-) method that should do the job:

```
// privilegeEvaluator is a WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator "autowired"
boolean allowed = privilegeEvaluator.isAllowed("/stuff/B", yourAuthentication);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use annotations like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

Annotations are standard way for Spring 3+

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the right place, the link you attached mentions what you need. Since you want access-control on your controller and check per user (not role) you can use the '@PreAuthorize' annotation with "hasPermission" expression or similar.

You could check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html) for expression-based access control and [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) for examples of custom security expression example in case you want to customize the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) First we need to know whether the user may enter the URL at all. This can be very easily achieved using WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.

```
privilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(contextPath, url, "GET", currentUser);
```

2) Now we need to identifying whether the user may access the handler method

```
private boolean isAllowedByAnnotation(Authentication currentUser, HandlerMethod method) {
    PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice advice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
    PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter voter = new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(advice);

    MethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    PrePostInvocationAttributeFactory factory = new ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory(expressionHandler);
    PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource = new PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource(factory);

    Class<?> controller = method.getBeanType();
    MethodInvocation mi = MethodInvocationUtils.createFromClass(controller, method.getMethod().getName());
    Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = metadataSource.getAttributes(method.getMethod(), controller);

    return PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.ACCESS_GRANTED == voter.vote(currentUser, mi, attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom PermissionEvaluator and use

hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object domainObject,
            Object permission).

```
  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    final DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
        new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));
    return expressionHandler;
  }

 @Bean
  public aclServiceImpl aclService() {
    final AclServiceImpl mutableAclService = new AclServiceImpl 
        (authorizationStrategy(), grantingStrategy());
    return mutableAclService;
  }
```

**AclServiceImpl** is the implementation of MutableAclService

Answer (score 0):

The most obviously useful annotation is **@PreAuthorize** which decides whether a method can actually be invoked or not. For example (from the"Contacts" sample application)

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

which means that access will only be allowed for users with the role **"ROLE_USER**". Obviously the same thing could easily be achieved using a traditional configuration and a simple configuration attribute for the required role. But what about:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#contact, 'admin')")
public void deletePermission(Contact contact, Sid recipient, Permission permission);
```

Here we’re actually using a method argument as part of the expression to decide whether the current user has the "admin"permission for the given contact. The built-in **hasPermission()** expression is linked into the Spring Security ACL module through the application context.

For More Detailed Explanation please refer this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html)